# MarkerClusterer not working only in webkit (Chrome and Safari), fine in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

This is driving me mental.

I'm using MarkerCluster with google maps v3, and it works fine in FF, however when I (and the client) kick it up in Chrome or Safari the clusters arn't there.

No errors, just not working in webkit.

A few notes: it's coming from some ajax-loaded json and it's in jquery.

This is the function taking care of the adding:

```
add_clusters: function() {
        markers = [];
        $.each( interpreters, function ( i, interpreter ){
            //maps.add_postcode_marker(i, 'interpreter');
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(interpreter.lat, interpreter.lng);
            //, map: map
            interpreters[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng });
            maps.add_info_box(i, "interpter");
            markers.push(interpreters[i].marker);
            app.log(interpreters[i].marker);
        });
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }
```

Cheers!

Just to reiterate, there are no errors in Chrome, it's just not displaying.

Comment: If the code is working,then might there be an extra code that doesn't work in chrome?Make sure there is no errors happening !

Comment: Just to reiterate, there are no errors in Chrome, it's just not displaying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with makercluster itself.

Line 725 specifically. Jquery was also included and the behaviour of .indexOf was changed slightly between browsers.

In firefox it was returning the correct -1.

However chrome was returning undefined.

You can fix it by changing line 725 to...

```
return this.markers_.indexOf(marker) != -1 && this.markers_.indexOf(marker) != undefined;
```

Comment: I have the same problem but i don't understand the answer. Where should i add this line?

Comment: i did this: download this script - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js - then go to line 825 and change this return `return this.markers_.indexOf(marker) != -1;` to that `return this.markers_.indexOf(marker) != -1 && this.markers_.indexOf(marker) != undefined;` then it will work on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I can't see what's wrong with this snippet.  It all looks good to me.

Can you use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to create a page that contains a working demo (in Firefox) so we can see it/try to edit it on our own?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with PrimeFaces. The solution was to make sure the response mimeType is `text/html`.