# google maps markers not showing in chrome and safari..Tried all answers on Stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am using google markers on my webpage.The latitude,longitude,name and detail are fetched from database using php page and then m using it on jquery using $.post method.

```php
<?php 

//Basic environment setup (error handling and logging, cookies/sessions, php directives         etc)
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../Config/path_config.php';
require_once C_PATH_UTILITY_MANAGER_PAGESETUP;
Page_Setup_Manager::setDefaultPageSettings();

require_once C_DIR_UTILITY_EVENTS_DATAACCESS;

$eventsdats=Eventsdata::getevents();
$temp=array();


foreach($eventsdats as $singlemapevent)
{
array_push($temp,array($singlemapevent['ename'],
     (floatval($singlemapevent['latitude'])),
    (floatval($singlemapevent['longitude'])),
    ($singlemapevent['edate']),
    ($singlemapevent['etime']),
    ($singlemapevent['edetail'])
    ));
}
echo json_encode($temp);

//Result[["Second Event",19.0554748,72.8497017,"17-12-2012","17:57 ","This is the  

social detail;"],["Demo Event",19.2097381,72.8737017,"08-12- 2012","09:34 ","This event  

was held in bhayander by ganesh mandhre"],]
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    

</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function initialize() {
    markers=[];
    temp=[];
    final_markers=[];
    $.post('maps_data.php',{},function(data){

       },"json").done(function(data){
           markers=(data);
           $.each(data,function(index,value){


            final_markers.push($.makeArray(value));

               });
           markers=final_markers;

       });
    alert(markers);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.0554748, 72.8497017);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        visible:true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style:   

google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: 

google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new 
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  


            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading"  class="firstHeading">'+markers[i][0]+'</h1>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p>'+markers[i][3]+'</p>'+
                    '<p>'+markers[i][4]+'</p>'+
                    '<p>'+markers[i][5]+'</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:350px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The markers are visible in firefox but not in chrome and safari..What is the error ? Am i using json incorrectly ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: "What is the error ?" - you tell us

Comment: possible duplicate of [MarkerClusterer not working only in webkit (Chrome and Safari), fine in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086837/markerclusterer-not-working-only-in-webkit-chrome-and-safari-fine-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

When you get your json data, you have to process them in the callback. Here you display the map and marker before the ajax call is complete. Move this rendering to the `done` callback.